# How to make the Spinner take only the space it currently needs?

Tags: android, width, android-spinner

### background

I'm trying to make a drop-down style spinner inside the actionMode of the actionBar.

Some of the items there have a large number of characters, and some just a few.

### The problem

When choosing the short items, I'd expect to see the spinner take the space the item takes, but actually, it takes the same size as the largest one.

Not only that, but if the text is too long, it won't allow to show it all using the marquee effect.

### What I've tried

I tried to make a customized layout for the spinner items, and set it to have a "wrap_content" for its width, but it doesn't work.

Here's a sample XML file based on the original simple_spinner_item.xml file of Android:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="inherit" />
```

### The question

How do I make the spinner take only the space it needs for its currently chosen item?

Also, how should I handle spinner items with long texts in them (some languages make it hard to be short in text)  ?

Should I maybe use a PopupMenu instead?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Important part is this. Put the below above code is your adapter and use `selectedItemPosition` for selecting text from objects array.

```
int selectedItemPosition = position;
        if (parent instanceof AdapterView) {
            selectedItemPosition = ((AdapterView) parent)
                    .getSelectedItemPosition();
        }
```

Example is given below.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View spinnerCell;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, inflate it from layout
            spinnerCell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_spinner_cell, parent, false);
        } else {
            spinnerCell = convertView;
        }
        int selectedItemPosition = position;
        if (parent instanceof AdapterView) {
            selectedItemPosition = ((AdapterView) parent)
                    .getSelectedItemPosition();
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) spinnerCell.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTitle);
        title.setText(titles[selectedItemPosition]);
        return spinnerCell;
    }
```

If you need an explanation follow this link: http://coding-thoughts.blogspot.in/2013/11/help-my-spinner-is-too-wide.html

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this help but maybe set spinner width to wrap content

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner_class"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: sorry but I tried it already... :(  Maybe it's this way because it extends from AdapterView.